# Equality in $\mathbb F_q\left(\left(\frac1T\right)\right)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, power-series, functional-equations

Can one characterize the $a\in\mathbb F_q\left(\left(\frac1T\right)\right)$ such that $a(T+1)=a(T)$? Although this seems elementary, I did not manage to find a answer.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you know any such $a$, other than constants, joaopa?

Comment: $a(T)\mapsto a(T+1)$ is a well-defined bicontinuous $K$-algebra automorphism of $K[[1/t]]$ and hence of $K((1/t))$. If it helps, writing $u=1/t$, it corresponds on $K[[u]]$ and $K((u))$ to $b(u)\mapsto b(u/(u+1))$. Since $u/(u+1)=u-u^2+u^3-\dots$, all this is meaningful.

Comment: @user44191: what is the problem with $a=1-\frac{1}{T}+\frac{1}{T^2}-\ldots$? Don't we have $a(T)=\frac{T}{1+T}$ and $a(T+1)=\frac{T+1}{T+2}==\frac{1+1/T}{1+2/T}\in \mathbb{F}_q((\frac{1}{T}))$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $t^p-t$ where $p$ is the characteristic. More generally, for arbitrary $f\in K((t))$, $K$ of characteristic $p$, one has $\prod_{n\in\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}}f(t+n)$.

Comment: Under the operator $D:a(t)\mapsto a(t+1)-a(t)$, the linear decomposition $K((t)))=k[t]\oplus t^{-1}k[[t^{-1}]]$ is stable. Hence it is enough to compute the kernel of $D$ (which is the OP's question) in restriction to $K[t]$ and $t^{-1}k[[t^{-1}]]$ separately. In $K[t]$, it's not hard to check that the kernel of $D$ has the basis $((t^p-t)^n)_{n\ge 0}$. (...I'll conclude in an answer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a field automorphism of order $p$, since $T+p=T$, so it fixes an index $p$ subfield. $\mathbb F_q (( \frac{1}{T^p - T } ))$ is an index $p$ subfield and is fixed, hence is the fixed field. This is the simplest example of a wildly ramified extension of local fields in equal characteristic, and is in particular an Artin-Schreier extension, generated over $\mathbb F_q((u))$ by the equation $T^p-T = u^{-1}$ where $u = \frac{1}{T^p - T}$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $K$ be an arbitrary field of prime characteristic $p$.

Consider the linear operator $D:a(t)\mapsto a(t+1)-a(t)$ of $K(\!(1/t)\!)$. It is well-defined, as it maps $t^{-n}$ to $$(t+1)^{-n}=t^{-n}(1+t^{-1})^{-n}=t^{-n}(1-t^{-1}+t^{-2}-t^{-3}+\cdots)^{n}.$$
The question is to determine the kernel of $D$.

> The kernel of $D$ is equal to the subalgebra $K(\!(1/(t^p-t))\!)$.

First, $D$ preserves $K[t]$. It preserves the obvious flag, mapping $t^n$ to a polynomial of degree $n$ if $p$ does not divide $n$, and of degree $<n$ if $p$ divides $n$. Therefore, the kernel $L_{\ge 0}$ of $D$ restricted to $K[t]$ has a basis $(P_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with $P_n$ of degree $np$; moreover for every sequence $(P_n)$ in this kernel of degree $pn$, the family $(P_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is a basis of $L_{\ge 0}$. Hence we can choose $P_n=(t^p-t)^n$.

In general, $D$ preserves $t^nK[\![1/t]\!]$ for every $n\in\mathbf{Z}$, and in particular preserves the decomposition $K[t]\oplus t^{-1}K[\![t^{-1}]\!]$.

Next, let $f\in K(\!(1/t)\!)$ be an arbitrary nonzero element of the kernel of $D$. For $n\in\mathbf{Z}$, decompose $(t^p-t)^nf$ in this decomposition:
$$(t^p-t)^nf(t)=Q_n(t^p-t)+R_n,\quad Q_n\in K[u],\;R_n\in t^{-1}K[\![t^{-1}]\!].$$
Hence $(t^p-t)^{n+1}f=Q_{n+1}(t^p-t)+R_{n+1}$, which dividing by $t^p-t$ yields
$$(t^p-t)^{n}f=\frac{Q_{n+1}(t^p-t)}{t^p-t}+\frac{R_{n+1}}{t^p-t}.$$
Write $Q_n(u)=Q_n(0)+uQ^*_n(u)$ with $Q_n^*\in K[u]$; then 
$$(t^p-t)^{n}f=Q_{n+1}^*(t^p-t)+\frac{Q_{n+1}(0)+R_{n+1}}{t^p-t}.$$
Hence $Q_{n+1}^*=Q_n$. That is, $$Q_n(u)=\frac{Q_{n+1}(u)-Q_{n+1}(0)}{u}.$$
It follows that there exists $Q(u)\in K(\!(1/u)\!)$ such that for all $n\in\mathbf{Z}$ (say $n\ge 0$ this is enough for us) we have $Q_n(u)=\pi(u^nQ(u))$, where $\pi$ is the projection to $K[u]$ in the decomposition $K(\!(1/u)\!)=K[u]\oplus u^{-1}K[\![1/u]\!]$. That is, $u^nQ(u)=Q_n(u)+R'_n(u)$ with $R'_n\in u^{-1}K[\![1/u]\!]$.
$$(t^p-t)^nf(t)=(t^p-t)^nQ(t^p-t)+R_n-R'_n.$$
Hence $f(t)-Q(t^p-t)\in (t^p-t)^{-n}K[\![1/t]\!]=t^{-pn}K[\![1/t]\!]$ for $n$ arbitrary large. This shows that $f(t)\in K(\!(1/(t^p-t))\!)$.

Comment: PS although this proof is easier at an undergraduate level, using plain linear algebra, Will Sawin's proof is conceptually much better.

Comment: Well I took Galois theory as an undergraduate. : ) Your proof is certainly better before one has taken that class.

Comment: @WillSawin Indeed I'm not familiar with the education system in your country. I had in mind 2 years of study, at a "common core" level, before more specialization in 3rd/4th year (as far as I know in France Galois theory is mostly in 4th year, mostly skipped by students specializing to probability or analysis).

Comment: An intermediate approach might be to first check that $\mathbb F_q((T^{-1}))$ is a $p$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_q(( (T^p-T)^{-1}))$ with basis $1,\dots, T^{p-1}$, and then express the automorphism by a matrix in this basis.

Comment: @WillSawin yes indeed this is what I thought after reading your answer. Actually when I wrote my answer I absolutely didn't have in mind that $K(\!(1/t)\!)$ and $K(\!(1/(t^p-t))\!)$ were fields!